# Transaction decoding is not available for chainId 1337 in hyperledger Besu

Tags: ethereum, hyperledger, smartcontracts, metamask, hyperledger-besu

I deployed a smart contract(simplestorage.sol) in Hyperledger Besu and I was able to call the smart contract and execute the smart contract. However, I got 「Transaction decoding is not available for chainId 1337」error and I cannot see the transaction data.

Does anyone know how to solve this error? I read it somewhere on the internet that some said this is not an error but it's a feature that is still not available in Metamask.

Can anyone clarify this? [image]

Comment: That is correct, Metamask has its own API's to decode the transaction details which it only supports for major chains.

Comment: So how to decode the transaction and is that error able to be solved?